# Can't select rows from table with user

Tags: sql, oracle

I created a user and granted him all permissions, i used: `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES TO user1;`
but then i tried to select rows from a table that i created with the admin user like this:
`select * from sys.table` it gives me an error message `table or view doesn't exist`

then i did: `Grant select on table to user1` and it worked.

so does all privileges not include select?

Comment: first off, never create/modify anything in the sys schema.

Comment: maybe you by mistake typed "from sys.table", try just "select * from table"

Comment: @Moebius the table wasn't created by the user so not prefixing the admin won't work and it didn't by the way.

Comment: @OldProgrammer i just started with sql and oracle so i'm just learning some manipulations.

Comment: @OldProgrammer - I don't see where the OP has created or modified anything in the SYS schema, can you please clarify? What I do see is that he has created another user, he has given that user all privileges, and that other user is trying to read data from a SYS table. That is perfectly fine (as long as that other user should, in fact, have the privileges to access SYS data).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As is often the case, Oracle uses words "approximately".

In this case, ALL doesn't mean "all". From the documentation:

ALL PRIVILEGES

> Specify ALL PRIVILEGES to grant all of the system privileges listed in
> Table 18-1, ***except*** the SELECT ANY DICTIONARY, ALTER DATABASE LINK, and
> ALTER PUBLIC DATABASE LINK privileges.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/GRANT.html#GUID-20B4E2C0-A7F8-4BC8-A5E8-BE61BDC41AC3

Notice the "except" part. "All" ***should*** mean "all", that is, "no exception"; yet........

Relevant to your question: ALL PRIVILEGES does not include SELECT ANY DICTIONARY. Most likely, whatever table or view you were trying to select from is a dictionary table (or view); which explains why granting ALL PRIVILEGES didn't work, but granting access directly on the table/view did.

If you want to grant access to all dictionary objects, you can grant SELECT ANY DICTIONARY to the user.

After you are done playing with these explicit grants, you may want to consider granting system **roles** to the users who need them (and **only** to those users), instead of hunting down all such exceptions.